# Using Usb Camera with Opencv Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am developing a neural network with python opencv.  It works when I turn on the laptop's own camera.  When I plug in an external usb camera, I don't get any response.  Independent of the program, only if I write opencv camera opening codes, it hangs.  The program does not close, it seems to be running, but nothing happens.  Why could it be?

Opening usb camera for opencv python

**My Source Code:**

```
img_height = 128
img_width = 128

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("modelson.h5")

camera_id = 1
camera_width = 1920
camera_height = 1080
camera_frame_rate = 30
camera_fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")

auto_percent = 0.2
auto_threshold = 127
auto_blur = 5

norm_alpha = 0
norm_beta = 255
```

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. show your research, your own debugging efforts, ...

Comment: cv2.VideoCapture(1). U have 2 cameras...one for built-in and USB camera

Comment: I Actualy using videoCapture(1) but freezing.

Comment: Can you post source code?

Comment: can you get video from these cameras using another program like VLC or the operating system's camera application?

Comment: Yeap, i get video another things. I will share source code when i from pc.

Comment: i added source code

Comment: that code isn't doing anything interesting, besides loading a model. [mre] please. on this site we must ask for a little more effort than that.

Answer (score 0):

The device index is just a number to determine which camera. Usually one camera will be connected (as in my case my camera id is 0). You can choose a second camera by changing `camera id : 1` to `camera id : 0` or `camera id : 2`. Camera id can be changed to index 0 - 9.

hope this can help you